# Finite automaton library in Scala including subset construction and minimization

Tags: functional-programming, scala

I built a scanner generator like flex or jflex in Scala for a class last year. Part of this project is a small library for handling and manipulating finite automata. It works completely as intended, except for maybe some bugs in the conversion to dot-code, which is of little concern.

I would like to have some aspects of this library reviewed, including but not limited to:

1. Quality and usefulness of the documentation of classes and methods
2. Application of functional concepts (tail recursion)
3. Naming of classes, methods, and variables
4. Simplicity and - more subjectively - elegance of solutions. Especially in my implementation of the subset construction to make the automaton deterministic.
5. ... and any other comment you may have

**References to code other than the supplied code**

The library uses a custom class for sets called `MySet`, which is outside of the scope of this question. I may ask for reviews for this class in another question. `MySet` supports using ranges as sets, complementary and difference sets without listing all values. It also provides the mathematical operators for unions, intersections, and differences.

**Code**

The library mainly consists of the class `AutomatonSpecification`, which encapsulates the list of transitions as well as start and accepting states.
It provides various methods to manipulate (create a manipulated copy) an automaton, most notably to remove epsilon transitions, make it deterministic via subset construction, and calculating a minimal automaton.

AutomatonSpecification.scala:

```scala
package automata.finiteautomata

/**
  * Encapsulates all aspects of a finite automaton.
  * This includes the transitions as well as the start and accepting states of the automaton
  *
  * @param transitions The transitions in this automaton
  * @param accepting   A list of accepting states along with their result value
  * @param start       The set of possible start states
  * @tparam InputElement The type of the input elements of the automaton
  * @tparam StateType    The type of the states in this automaton
  * @tparam Result       The result type of this automaton
  */
case class AutomatonSpecification[InputElement, StateType <: State[StateType], Result]
(transitions: List[Transition[InputElement, StateType]], accepting: List[Acceptance[StateType, Result]], start: Set[StateType]) {

  /**
    * Finds the epsilon closure of a given state.
    * Calculates the epsilon closures of all epsilon reachable states as a byproduct.
    *
    * @param state         The state to find the epsilon closure of
    * @param knownClosures A map containing known epsilon closures. Acts as a cache.
    * @return A tuple consisting of 1. The set of epsilon reachable states and 2. A map of all known epsilon closures
    */
  def epsilonClosureOf(state: StateType, knownClosures: Map[StateType, Set[StateType]] = Map()): (Set[StateType], Map[StateType, Set[StateType]]) = {
    def helper(currentState: StateType, known: Map[StateType, Set[StateType]], visitedStates: Set[StateType]): (Set[StateType], Map[StateType, Set[StateType]]) = {
      if (visitedStates.contains(currentState)) return (visitedStates, known)

      val visited = visitedStates + currentState

      known.get(currentState) match {
        case Some(closure) => (closure, known)
        case None =>
          val (c, k) =
            transitions
              .filter(t => t.oldState == currentState && t.condition == EpsilonCondition)
              .map(_.newState).toSet
              .foldLeft((visited, known)) {
                case ((newVisited, newKnown), reachablestate) =>
                  //Get the transitive closure of the epsilon-reachable state
                  //All known closures (f._2) are passed on
                  //Already visited states (f._1) are also passed on.
                  //The last part is needed to correctly handle cycles of epsilon-reachable states
                  val (closure, newknown) = helper(reachablestate, newKnown, newVisited)

                  (newVisited ++ closure, newknown)
              }

          (c, k + (currentState -> c))
      }
    }

    helper(state, knownClosures, Set())
  }

  /**
    * Finds the epsilon closure of all states of this automaton
    *
    * @return A map containing the epsilon closures of all states.
    */
  def allEpsilonClosures: Map[StateType, Set[StateType]] = this.states.foldLeft(Map[StateType, Set[StateType]]())(
    (k, state) => this.epsilonClosureOf(state, k)._2)

  /**
    * Tail recursive function to remove all epsilon transitions in a specification of a finite automaton in an iterative manner
    *
    * @return The specification of an equivalent automaton without any epsilon transitions
    */
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  final def withoutEpsilonIterative: AutomatonSpecification[InputElement, StateType, Result] = {
    //If there are no epsilon transitions left, return the argument
    if (this.transitions.forall(_.condition != EpsilonCondition)) return this

    val transformed: List[(List[Transition[InputElement, StateType]], Option[Acceptance[StateType, Result]])] =
      this.transitions.map {
        case Transition(a, EpsilonCondition, b) if a == b =>
          (Nil, None) //Reflective epsilon transitions are meaningless and result in infinite loops.
        case Transition(oldState, EpsilonCondition, newState) =>
          //1. Replace epsilon transition with all possible transitive transitions (potentially including new epsilon-transitions)
          //2. If the target state was accepting, add the initial state to the set of accepting states
          (this.transitions.filter(_.oldState == newState).map(x => Transition(oldState, x.condition, x.newState)),
            this.accepting.find(_.state == newState).map(_.copy(state = oldState)))
        case t => (List(t), None) //All non-epsilon transitions are kept
      }


    //tailrecursive call to eliminate the next set of epsilon transitions
    AutomatonSpecification(transformed.flatMap(_._1), transformed.flatMap(_._2) ++ this.accepting,
                           this.start).withoutEpsilonIterative
  }

  /**
    * Removes all epsilon transitions in the specification.
    * Curiously around 4x slower than 'withoutEpsilonIterative' for small automata.
    * The resulting specification may contain unreachable states
    *
    * @return The specification of an equivalent automaton without any epsilon transitions.
    */
  def withoutEpsilon: AutomatonSpecification[InputElement, StateType, Result] = {
    val closures = this.allEpsilonClosures

    val transitions = for (state <- this.states.toList;
                           closing <- closures(state);
                           transition <- this.transitions.filter(
                             _.oldState == closing) if transition.condition != EpsilonCondition)
      yield transition.copy(oldState = state)

    val accepting = this.accepting.flatMap({
      case Acceptance(state, result) => closures.filter({
        case (_, value) => value.contains(state)
      }).keys.map(s => Acceptance(s, result)).toList
    })

    AutomatonSpecification(transitions, accepting, this.start.flatMap(closures)).cullAcceptingStates
  }

  /**
    * Makes the automaton deterministic by constructing all reachable state-subsets.
    * Requires the specification to not contain any epsilon transition.
    * Removes unreachable states as a byproduct.
    *
    * @return A new specification containing aggregate states and no sources of non-deterministic behaviour
    */
  def toDeterministic: AutomatonSpecification[InputElement, AggregateState[StateType], Result] =
    this.toDeterministic(AggregateState(this.start))

  /**
    * Makes the automaton deterministic by constructing all reachable state-subsets.
    * Requires the specification to not contain any epsilon transition.
    * Removes unreachable states as a byproduct.
    *
    * @param aggregateStartState An aggregate start state
    * @return A new specification containing aggregate states and no sources of non-deterministic behaviour
    */
  private def toDeterministic(aggregateStartState: AggregateState[StateType]): AutomatonSpecification[InputElement, AggregateState[StateType], Result] = {
    case class StateTransition(condition: TransitionCondition[InputElement], target: AggregateState[StateType])

    /**
      * Transforms a list of non-deterministic transitions for a given state into a list of usable deterministic transitions
      *
      * @param current     The current aggregate state
      * @param transitions A list of all transitions that can be taken from the current state
      * @return A usable list of AggregateTransitions with no remaining sources of non-determinism
      */
    def solveAll(current: AggregateState[StateType], transitions: List[StateTransition]): List[Transition[InputElement, AggregateState[StateType]]] = {
      val resolved = resolveAllCollisions(transitions)

      resolved.map(t => Transition[InputElement, AggregateState[StateType]](current, t.condition, t.target))
    }

    /**
      * Transforms a list of non-deterministic transitions into a list of deterministic transitions
      *
      * @param transitions A list of possible transitions
      * @return A list of deterministic transitions without the origin state
      */
    def resolveAllCollisions(transitions: List[StateTransition]): List[StateTransition] = {
      transitions match {
        case Nil => Nil
        case head :: Nil => head :: Nil
        case head :: tail =>
          resolveCollisionsForSingleHead(head, tail) match {
            case Some(replacement) => resolveAllCollisions(replacement)
            case None => head :: resolveAllCollisions(tail)
          }
      }
    }

    /**
      * Resolves the first collision between a given transition and any of a list of transitions
      *
      * @param head The transition to resolve collisions with
      * @param tail List of all potential collision candidates
      * @return None if there was no collision, some list of transitions if there was a collision that was replaced.
      *         The list is functionally equivalent to all transitions head :: tail
      */
    def resolveCollisionsForSingleHead(head: StateTransition, tail: List[StateTransition]): Option[List[StateTransition]] = {
      @scala.annotation.tailrec
      def helper(tail: List[StateTransition], safe: List[StateTransition]): Option[List[StateTransition]] = {
        tail match {
          case Nil => None
          case next :: ts => resolveOptionalCollision(head, next) match {
            case None => helper(ts, next :: safe)
            case Some(replacement) => Some(replacement.filterNot(_.condition.isEmpty) ::: ts ::: safe)
          }
        }
      }

      helper(tail, Nil)
    }

    /**
      * Resolves the collision between to transitions
      *
      * @param a The first transition
      * @param b The second transition
      * @return None if there was no collision, some list of transitions if the transitions collide and need to be replaced.
      *         The list may contain "empty" transitions, i.e. SetConditions that with empty character sets.
      *         While not harmful, they should be filtered for efficiency.
      */
    def resolveOptionalCollision(a: StateTransition, b: StateTransition): Option[List[StateTransition]] = {
      (a, b) match {
        case (StateTransition(SetCondition(t1), aNew), StateTransition(SetCondition(t2), bNew)) =>
          val intersect = t1 ∩ t2

          if (intersect.isEmpty) None
          else Some(List(
            StateTransition(SetCondition(t1 \ t2), aNew),
            StateTransition(SetCondition(t2 \ t1), bNew),
            StateTransition(SetCondition(intersect), aNew ++ bNew)
            ))
        case _ => None
      }
    }

    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def constructAggregateStatesAndTransitions(queue: List[AggregateState[StateType]], known: Set[AggregateState[StateType]], transes: List[Transition[InputElement, AggregateState[StateType]]]): (Set[AggregateState[StateType]], List[Transition[InputElement, AggregateState[StateType]]]) = {
      queue match {
        case Nil => (known, transes)
        case head :: tail if known.contains(head) => constructAggregateStatesAndTransitions(tail, known, transes)
        case head :: tail =>
          val resolved: List[Transition[InputElement, AggregateState[StateType]]] = {
            //Filter transitions on the old state, and map to an instance of C
            val cs = this.transitions.filter(t => head.states.contains(t.oldState)).map(
              t => StateTransition(t.condition, AggregateState(Set(t.newState))))
            solveAll(head, cs) //Solve the collisions in those transitions
          }

          val newStates = resolved.map(
            _.newState) //Get all aggregate states, are can be reached by the resolved transitions

          //Recursive call to get transitions of all remaining aggregate states, adding the newly found states to the queue
          constructAggregateStatesAndTransitions(newStates ++ tail, known + head, resolved.map(
            t => Transition[InputElement, AggregateState[StateType]](head, t.condition, t.newState)) ::: transes)
      }
    }

    //Compound expression to hide variables from nested functions
    {
      //Construct all reachable aggregate states and the corresponding transitions
      val (states, ts) = constructAggregateStatesAndTransitions(aggregateStartState :: Nil, Set(), Nil)

      val accepting = this.accepting.flatMap({
        case Acceptance(state, result) => states.filter(value => value.states.contains(state)).map(
          s => Acceptance(s, result)).toList
      })

      AutomatonSpecification(ts, accepting, Set(aggregateStartState)).cullAcceptingStates
    }
  }

  /**
    * Maps all states to a numbered state, to make it more convenient to use.
    *
    * @return An updated specification containing numbered states.
    */
  def withNumberedStates: AutomatonSpecification[InputElement, NumberedState, Result] =
    this.mapStates(this.getIntegralStateMap)

  /**
    * Maps all states in this specification.
    * Guaranteed to preserve determinism if 'f' is injective.
    *
    * @param f The function, that maps old states to new states.
    * @tparam NewState The type of the new states
    * @return An updated specification.
    */
  def mapStates[NewState <: State[NewState]](f: StateType => NewState): AutomatonSpecification[InputElement, NewState, Result] = AutomatonSpecification(
    this.transitions.map(_.mapStates(f)), this.accepting.map(a => a.copy(state = f(a.state))), this.start.map(f))

  /**
    * @return A Set of all States in this Automaton
    */
  def states: Set[StateType] = this.transitions.flatMap(t => List(t.oldState, t.newState)).toSet ++ this.start

  /**
    * Removes all redundant and therefore ineffective accepting states
    *
    * @return A new automaton specification without the redundant acceptances
    */
  private def cullAcceptingStates: AutomatonSpecification[InputElement, StateType, Result] = {
    def filter(ac: List[Acceptance[StateType, Result]]): List[Acceptance[StateType, Result]] = {
      ac match {
        case Nil => Nil
        case head :: tail => head :: filter(tail.filterNot(_.state == head.state))
      }
    }

    this.copy(accepting = filter(this.accepting))
  }

  /**
    * Minimizes the automaton using Brzozowski’s algorithm.
    * Limitation: Only works correctly when all results of accepting states are equal.
    *
    * @return A minimized automaton with aggregate states
    */
  def minimized: AutomatonSpecification[InputElement, AggregateState[AggregateState[StateType]], Result] =
    this.reversed.toDeterministic.reversed.toDeterministic

  /**
    * Reverses the automaton.
    * The result automaton accepts the reversed language of this automaton.
    * Only works when all semantics of accepting states are equal.
    *
    * @return A potentially non-deterministic finite automaton specification, that accepts the reversed language.
    */
  def reversed: AutomatonSpecification[InputElement, StateType, Result] =
    AutomatonSpecification(
      this.transitions.map(_.reverse),
      this.start.map(s => Acceptance(s, this.accepting.head.result)).toList,
      this.accepting.map(_.state).toSet
      )


  /**
    * Groups transistion edges by their start- and end-node.
    * Merges the transitions that can be merged
    *
    * @return A new AutomatonSpecification with the combined transitions
    */
  def mergeTransitions: AutomatonSpecification[InputElement, StateType, Result] = {
    def union(a: TransitionCondition[InputElement], b: TransitionCondition[InputElement]): TransitionCondition[InputElement] = (a, b) match {
      case (EpsilonCondition, EpsilonCondition) => EpsilonCondition
      case (EpsilonCondition, other) => other
      case (other, EpsilonCondition) => other
      case (SetCondition(lhs), SetCondition(rhs)) => SetCondition(lhs ∪ rhs)
    }

    val mergedTransitions = this.transitions.groupBy(t => (t.oldState, t.newState)).map({
      case ((old, target), trans) =>
        Transition(old, trans.map(_.condition).reduce(union), target)
    }).toList

    this.copy(transitions = mergedTransitions)
  }

  /**
    * Creates a dot graph-representation of this automaton.
    *
    * @return A string in valid dot-syntax for graphical representation
    */
  def toDot(f: InputElement => String = _.toString): String = {
    val regularstates = this.states &~ this.accepting.map(_.state).toSet &~ this.start
    val statemap = this.getIntegralStateMap.mapValues(_.state.toString)

    s"""digraph G{
       |  {
       |    node[shape=circle style=filled fillcolor=white]
       |    ${
      this.accepting.map(
        a => s"""${statemap(a.state)} [shape=doublecircle, label="${a.state.toDot}(${a.result})"]""").mkString("\n    ")
    }
       |    ${this.start.map(a => s"""${statemap(a)} [fillcolor=yellow label="${a.toDot}"]""").mkString("\n    ")}
       |    ${regularstates.map(a => s"""${statemap(a)} [label="${a.toDot}"]""").mkString("\n    ")}
       |  }
       |  ${this.transitions.map(t => s"${t.toDot(statemap, f)};").mkString("\n  ")}
       |}
     """.stripMargin
  }

  /**
    * Creates a human-readable representation of this automaton
    *
    * @return A string describing the automaton
    */
  override def toString: String = s"Automaton Specification: Start with $start, End with $accepting:\n${
    this.transitions.mkString("\n")
  }"

  /**
    * Maps all states of this automaton to a numbered state
    *
    * @return A map containing a numbered state for every state this automaton contains
    */
  private def getIntegralStateMap: Map[StateType, NumberedState] =
    this.states.zipWithIndex.toMap.mapValues(NumberedState)

  /**
    * Merges this automaton with another automaton.
    * The merge is done by mapping the states of the second automaton to remove all clashes and keeping the starting states of both automatons.
    * The resulting automaton is by nature non-deterministic.
    *
    * @param other The second automaton.
    * @return A new automaton specification whose accepted language is the union of both automatons.
    */
  def mergeWith(other: AutomatonSpecification[InputElement, StateType, Result]): AutomatonSpecification[InputElement, StateType, Result] = {
    val highest = this.getHighestStateIndex + 1
    val transformed = other.mapStates(_ + highest)

    AutomatonSpecification(this.transitions ::: transformed.transitions, this.accepting ::: transformed.accepting,
                           this.start ++ transformed.start)
  }

  private def getHighestStateIndex: Int = this.states.map(_.max).max
}
```

Accompanying this class are some small classes representing states and transitions located in the package object.

package.scale:

```scala
package automata

package object finiteautomata {
  /**
    * A state for a finite automaton
    *
    * @tparam ConcreteState The concrete State class
    */
  sealed trait State[ConcreteState] {
    /**
      * Adds an offset to all relevant statenumbers of this state
      *
      * @param offset The offset to add
      * @return A new ConcreteState including the offset
      */
    def +(offset: Int): ConcreteState

    /**
      * @return A dot-representation of this state
      */
    def toDot: String

    /**
      * @return The maximum state number that is used in this state
      */
    def max: Int
  }

  /**
    * A simple numbered state for finite automata
    *
    * @param state The state number
    */
  case class NumberedState(state: Int) extends State[NumberedState] {
    override def +(offset: Int): NumberedState = NumberedState(state + offset)
    override def toDot: String = state.toString
    override def max: Int = this.state
  }

  /**
    * An aggregate state for finite automata. Represents the union of multiple base states.
    *
    * @param states The base states included in this aggregate state
    * @tparam BaseState The type of the base states
    */
  case class AggregateState[BaseState <: State[BaseState]](states: Set[BaseState]) extends State[AggregateState[BaseState]] {
    def ++(other: AggregateState[BaseState]): AggregateState[BaseState] = AggregateState(this.states ++ other.states)

    override def +(offset: Int): AggregateState[BaseState] = AggregateState(this.states.map(_ + offset))
    override def toDot: String = s"{${this.states.map(_.toDot).mkString(",")}}"
    override def max: Int = states.map(_.max).max
  }

  /**
    * Represents an accepting state by associating a result with it
    *
    * @param state  The accepting state
    * @param result The result of the automaton if it halts in the accepting state
    * @tparam State  The state type of the automaton
    * @tparam Result The result type of the automaton
    */
  case class Acceptance[State, Result](state: State, result: Result)

  /**
    * Abstract base for transition conditions of a finite automaton
    *
    * @tparam InputElement The type of input elements for the automaton
    */
  sealed trait TransitionCondition[+InputElement] {

    /**
      * @return True if the transition can never be triggered, false otherwise
      */
    def isEmpty: Boolean

    /**
      * Creates a dot-representation for this transition
      *
      * @param f A mapping function to map InputElements to a dot-representation
      * @return The completed dot-representation
      */
    def toDot(f: InputElement => String = _.toString): String
  }

  /**
    * A transition condition described by a set of all input elements that can trigger the transition
    *
    * @param set A set containing all elements that trigger the associated transition
    * @tparam InputElement The type of input elements for the automaton
    */
  case class SetCondition[InputElement](set: automata.util.sets.MySet[InputElement]) extends TransitionCondition[InputElement] {
    override def isEmpty: Boolean = set.isEmpty
    override def toDot(f: InputElement => String = _.toString): String = set.toFormattedString(f)
  }

  /**
    * The epsilon transition condition. Always triggers and consumes no input
    */
  case object EpsilonCondition extends TransitionCondition[Nothing] {
    override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
    override def toDot(f: Nothing => String = _.toString): String = "ϵ"
  }

  /**
    * Represents a complete transition of an automaton
    *
    * @param oldState  The origin state for this transition
    * @param condition The condition on which the transition is triggered
    * @param newState  The target state of this transition.
    * @tparam InputElement The type of input elements for the automaton
    * @tparam StateType    The type of states in the automaton
    */
  case class Transition[+InputElement, StateType <: State[StateType]](oldState: StateType,
                                                                      condition: TransitionCondition[InputElement],
                                                                      newState: StateType) {

    /**
      * Applies a function on the origin and target states of this transition
      *
      * @param f The mapping function
      * @tparam NewState The type of the new states
      * @return A new Transition describing the reverse direction of this transition
      */
    def mapStates[NewState <: State[NewState]](f: StateType => NewState): Transition[InputElement, NewState] =
      Transition[InputElement, NewState](f(this.oldState), condition, f(this.newState))

    /**
      * Reverses the transition by flipping origin and target states.
      *
      * @return The new, reversed transition
      */
    def reverse: Transition[InputElement, StateType] = Transition(newState, condition, oldState)

    /**
      * @return A simple string representation of the transistion
      */
    override def toString: String = {
      s"$oldState with $condition to $newState"
    }

    /**
      * @param statemap A function that maps states to their dot-representation
      * @param f        A function that maps input elements to their dot-representation
      * @return A dot representation for this transition
      */
    def toDot(statemap: StateType => String, f: InputElement => String = _.toString): String = {
      s"""${statemap(oldState)} -> ${statemap(newState)} [label="${condition.toDot(f)}"]"""
    }
  }
}
```